# ConditionalAttribute vs Comments

Tags: c#, attributes, c-preprocessor, compiler-directives

I just read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute.aspx.

And I'm struggling to understand what the difference is between using

```
[Conditional("CONDITION1")]
```

with/without

```
#define CONDITION1
```

and just commenting/uncommenting a method?

Is the only purpose of ConditionalAttribute to make the compiler ignore a method or attribute? If so, why not juse use a comment? If not, what are the advantages compared to just using comments?

Comment: You can easily define symbols at build time e.g. `csc /define:CONDITION1`. It's much harder to comment out entire method bodies.

Comment: Seems to me you will be able to re-use it for multiple methods. That way you won't have half your code in comments but you just have that one `#define CONDITION1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With conditional attributes you can enable and disable multiple parts of code with a single step, rather than having to hunt through your source code and comment/uncomment multiple locations.

Conditional attributes can also provide information as to *why* certain code is enabled or disabled (e.g. for debugging purposes etc.)

Also, you should prefer conditional attributes to conditional compilation (`#if` etc.), as explained in [Effective C#](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/csharp/9780321659149/csharp-language-idioms/ch01lev1sec4).